# setState depend on values from another class

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I face a little problem as I think.

I want to show a widget and hide it depend on values from another class, here is a small code that will explain what I mean.

I used `Visibility` to hide and show `Hello world` message.

```
Visibility(
   visible: showAlert().getAlertVisible(),
   child: Text(
           "Hello World"
        ),
    )
```

`showAlert().getAlertVisible()` I got it from another class and it's will be true or false.

This is the `Class`

```
class showAlert{

  bool alertVisible = false;

  void setAlertVisible(bool value){
    alertVisible = value;
  }

  bool getAlertVisible(){
    return alertVisible;
  }

  void show(Duration duration){

    setAlertVisible(false);
    setAlertVisible(true);

    Future.delayed(
        duration,
            (){
          setAlertVisible(false);
        }
    );
  }
}
```

**My Problem:** when the value changed in `class showAlert` nothing change in interface because I don't use `setState()`, How can I use `setState()` when value change or gets live listening??

Comment: Read about state management for Flutter. BLoC/Redux/ScopedModel

Comment: If you need simple solution see (https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple)

Comment: i think provider could be best solution for this kind of problem specially value provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ValueNotifier` and `AnimatedBuilder`:

```
class ShowAlert{
  ValueNotifier<bool> alertVisible = ValueNotifier(false);

  void show(Duration duration){
    alertVisible.value = true;
    Future.delayed(duration, ()=> alertVisible.value = false);
  }
}
```

```
void main() {
  final showAlert = ShowAlert();
  showAlert.show(Duration(seconds: 5));
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: showAlert.alertVisible,
          builder: (context, _) {
            return Visibility(
              visible: showAlert.alertVisible.value,
              child: Text("Hello World"),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

The AnimatedBuilder will rebuild its children when the ValueNotifier's value changes.

Comment: Thank you, it works well now but I'm wondering is this way best practice?

Comment: Lifting the state up or using a controller with `ChangeNotifier` are the best ways to manage state in flutter without external packages.

Comment: I have also experimented with `InheritedWidget` and `InheritedModel` and made the inherited_store package: https://pub.dev/packages/inherited_store

Comment: When an inherited widget gets rebuilt, only children that refer to it will get rebuilt. for example if you use `Theme.of(context).accentColor` and the theme widget changes, than only widgets that have called  `Theme.of(context)` will get rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

Extend `ChangeNotifier`:

```
class ShowAlert extends ChangeNotifier{
  bool alertVisible = false;

  void show(Duration duration) {
    alertVisible = true;
    notifyListeners();

    Future.delayed(duration, () {
      alertVisible = false;
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }
}
```

```
void main() {
  final showAlert = ShowAlert();
  showAlert.show(Duration(seconds: 5));
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: showAlert,
          builder: (context, _) {
            return Visibility(
              visible: showAlert.alertVisible,
              child: Text("Hello World"),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

The `ChangeNotifier` class implements the `Listenable` interface.

Comment: I recommend this method, as it only requires extending `ChangeNotifier` and wrapping the part you need to be rebuilt with an `AnimatedBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mixin`s:

```
mixin ShowAlert<T extends StatefulWidget> on State<T> {
  bool alertVisible = false;

  void show(Duration duration) {
    setState(() {
      alertVisible = true;
    });
    Future.delayed(duration, () {
      setState(() {
        alertVisible = false;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyApp(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with ShowAlert<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () {
            show(Duration(seconds: 5));
          },
          child: Text('show'),
        ),
        Visibility(
          visible: alertVisible,
          child: Text("Hello World"),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```